# Getting a Deployment Validation Error "Unknown user permission: TraceXdsQueries"

Tags: deployment

I'm getting this issue, "Unknown user permission: TraceXdsQueries" when I try to validate our package in one of our sandboxes.

This is the only remaining error in our package and we couldn't find any mention of this error in Google at all.

Has anyone encountered this issue so far? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any IDE or have the ability to search through all your metadata for references to that "TraceXdsQueries"? Also, are you pushing profiles and if so, are there major differences between the two orgs when it comes to installed packages?

Comment: I don't use IDEs but I do use workbench. I extracted the metadata of the profile and found the TraceXdsQueries. I haven't made a comparison with the installed packages yet so I'll do that now. Thanks for the tip, I'll get back to you if I find anything. Thanks.

Comment: I have also faced this issue. I think,this is sandbox up-gradation issue. when I am trying to deploy from Winter20 sandbox to Summer19 sandbox, I am getting this issue. Please check your destination sandbox release version.

Comment: Ok. That explains it. My destination sandbox has different version with my current sandbox. The solution for this currently is to manually remove the tag in the profile metadata. Really tedious, but it's a good workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to make a workaround for this issue. It's tedious, but at least we're no longer blocked with our deployment.

What you need to do is go to the profile metadata that is causing the issue and remove the tag "TraceXdsQueries".

Validate the profile again and this time you should not encounter the issue anymore.